# How to bind dropdown value to Pinia state in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

I am trying to bind a Pinia state value to a dropdown, and also have this dropdown mutate the state. I think my approach is causing a circular reference with a `computed` variable. The `onChange()` function isn't actually changing the state.

This is my component:

```
<script setup>

import { useMyStore } from '@/stores/myStore';
import { computed } from 'vue';

const myStore = useMyStore();

// convert the stored value to string for dropdown
const dropdownVal = computed(() => {
    const stringVal = myStore.numVal.toString();
    return stringVal
})

// I think this is the issue 
const onChange = () =>{
    myStore.numVal = parseInt(dropdownVal.value);
}

</script>

<template>
<select v-model="dropdownVal" @change="onChange()">
<option value='1'>Option 1</option>
<option value='2'>Option 2</option>
<option value='3'>Option 3</option>
</select>
</template>
```

I have another component that also modifies `myStore.numVal` and I need this to be reflected in the dropdown when state changes (It's just using a `.$reset()`).

Comment: You probably want to use `const numVal = storeToRefs(myStore)` and then read it `numVal.value` instead of just `numVal`. That assuming that yout numVal in store is a ref.

Comment: I would use `storeToRefs()` instead of the `computed()`? Would that change the `onChange()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @entio for the comment, I was able to achieve what I wanted with the following:

I had to use `storeToRefs()` in order to maintain reactivity within the computed variable.

```
<script setup>

import { useMyStore } from '@/stores/myStore';
import { computed } from 'vue';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const myStore = storeToRefs(useMyStore());

// convert the stored value to string for dropdown
const dropdownVal = computed(() => {
    const stringVal = myStore.numVal.value.toString();
    return stringVal
})

// I think this is the issue 
const onChange = () =>{
    myStore.numVal.value = parseInt(dropdownVal.value);
}

</script>

<template>
<select v-model="myStore.numVal.value" @change="onChange()">
<option value='1'>Option 1</option>
<option value='2'>Option 2</option>
<option value='3'>Option 3</option>
</select>
</template>
```

Comment: Please add some TL; DR section to your post highlighting that one HAS to use storeToRefs to maintain reactivity. Otherwise people coming here from google will most likely end up not getting anything.

Comment: And please mark your answer as accepted if you have solved your problem.